# Craft CMS Routing to plugin controller action Error- HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: craftcms

I am new to Craft (coming from Laravel) and I am getting a 404 error when trying to route to controller action for a plugin created with pluginfactory.io.  The plugin installed with no issues, but I cannot seem to find a way to execute the controller actions.

Here is the relevant directory structure

```
├── composer.json
├── config
│   ├── app.php
│   ├── db.php
│   ├── general.php
│   ├── license.key
│   ├── redactor
│   └── routes.php
├── modules
│   └── Module.php
├── plugins
│   └── signup
│       ├── composer.json
│       └── src
│           ├── Signup.php

│           ├── controllers
│           │   ├── EnrollmentController.php
│           ├── models
│           │   ├── Enrollment.php
│           │   └── Settings.php
```

I have tried the default controller route for my EnrollmentController: http://localhost:8080/actions/signup/enrollment/index using the /plugin/controller/action format, and the request never reaches the controller.  I ran into the same problem when I tried to create a custom module.

Here is the code for my EnrollmentController

```
namespace wolff\signup\controllers;

use wolff\signup\Enrollment;

use Craft;
use craft\web\Controller;

class EnrollmentController extends Controller
{
    protected $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $result = 'Welcome to the EnrollmentController actionIndex() method';

        die($result);
    }
```

Here is the stack trace for the 404

```
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request "signup/enrollment/index". in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:537
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(299): yii\base\Module->runAction('signup/enrollme...', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(566): craft\web\Application->runAction('signup/enrollme...', Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(278): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}

Next yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Page not found. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php:570
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(278): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm the plugin or module is actually loaded and running? Try `die`-ing inside your plugin's `init()` method.

The next thing I would check is if your plugin is setting the correct `$controllerNamespace` inside it's `init()` method. Look at another plugin from the plugin store to see how they are doing it. Typically you will have a different `$controllerNamespace` if Craft is run as a console application.

If all of the above seems correct. Try manually setting a URL inside your plugin's `init()` method to see if that resolves the issue. 
From the CraftCMS docs- setting a CP URL:

```php
<?php
use craft\events\RegisterUrlRulesEvent;
use craft\web\UrlManager;
use yii\base\Event;

// init
Event::on(UrlManager::class, UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES, function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
    $event->rules['cocktails/new'] = ['template' => 'cocktails/_edit'];
    $event->rules['cocktails/<widgetId:\d+>'] = 'cocktails/edit-cocktail';
});
```

Setting a site URL:

```php
<?php
use craft\events\RegisterUrlRulesEvent;
use craft\web\UrlManager;
use yii\base\Event;

// init
Event::on(UrlManager::class, UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES, function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
    $event->rules['cocktails/new'] = ['template' => 'cocktails/_edit'];
    $event->rules['cocktails/<widgetId:\d+>'] = 'cocktails/edit-cocktail';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways by which you can execute controller method for a plugin.

**1. By form action:**

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="demo-plugin/default/index">
```

In this ,demo-plugin is my plugin handle default is my controller and index is controller's action  method.

**2. By Defining control Panel route inside your Plugin.php file:**

```
UrlManager::class,
UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES,
function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
    $event->rules['contactform'] = 'demo-plugin/default/show';
}
```